# Place parts of a for loop into function in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have several functions that use this given for loop below.

```
function startClaw(dir){
    var readCount = 0;
    for(var isRead in qdata){
        readCount++;
        if(qdata[isRead]['reading'] == true){
            return;
        }else if(readCount == 5){
            isAnimating = $("#claw").is(':animated');
            if(!isAnimating){// prevents multiple clicks during animation
                if(isMoving || isDropping){ return; }
                MCI = setInterval(function(){ moveClaw(dir); },10);
                //console.log("startClaw:" + dir);
                stopSwingClaw();    
            }
        }
    }
}
//.................................................................
function dropClaw(){
    var readCount = 0;
    for(var isRead in qdata){
        readCount++;
        if(qdata[isRead]['reading'] == true){
            return;
        }else if(readCount == 5){
            if(isDropping){ return; } //prevent multiple clicks
            stopSwingClaw();
            isDropping = true;  
            MCI = setInterval(moveDown,20); //start heartbeat
        }
    }
}
```

Everything in the `else if` statement is different within the various functions. I'm wondering if there is any way to place the "pieces" of the for loop on the outside of the `else if` into its very own function. I feel like I've seen this or had done this a very long time ago, but it escapes me and I couldn't find any examples. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sure, but how depends on what you actually need to do in those various functions.

Comment: Just realized I'll probably catch flak for using a `for-in` loop. It's iterating over the array objects purposefully instead of running through sequentially. It's fine in the case I'm using it in my code.

Comment: Not enough known here

Comment: @DaveNewton It's the same written code for the for loops. It's literally just 3 different functions that have different things going on in the else if statement

Comment: Going to need to be more specific by at least providing 2 examples that show the code redundancy and some indication of different logic in the loops. What you have provided so far is too vague for anyone to productively help. See [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previewing, I see this is similar to the above. Two differences (it looks like) are here the count gets passed to the function in case they needed to ever have different checks in the if statement, and, it's checking what the return value is since it looks like you return out of the loop if the condition is met. There are notes in comments in the code below.

```
function startClaw(dir) {
  // Pass a function as a callback to the method which expects to receive the count as a param
  doReadCount(qdata, function(theCount) { 
    if (theCount === 5) {
      isAnimating = $("#claw").is(':animated');
      if (!isAnimating) { // prevents multiple clicks during animation
        if (isMoving || isDropping) {
          return true;
        }
        MCI = setInterval(function() { moveClaw(dir); }, 10);
        //console.log("startClaw:" + dir);
        stopSwingClaw();
      }

      return false;
  });
}
//.................................................................
function dropClaw() {
  // Pass a function as a callback to the method which expects to receive the count as a param
  doReadCount(qdata, function(theCount) {
    if (theCount === 5) {
      if (isDropping) {
        return;
      } //prevent multiple clicks

      stopSwingClaw();
      isDropping = true;
      MCI = setInterval(moveDown,20); //start heartbeat
    }
  });
}

function doReadCount(qdata, elseFunction) {
  var readCount = 0;
  var elseReturn;
  for (var isRead in qdata) {
      readCount++;
      if (qdata[isRead]['reading'] == true) {
                return;
      } else {
        // call the function that was sent and pass it the current read count. If the return is true, then also return true here
        elseReturn = elseFunction(readCount);
        if (elseReturn) {
            return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes! A callback function is exactly what I was looking for. This keeps it clean and still gets the job done I need. Thanks a ton! I seriously hadn't made a callback function in a few years (let alone used javascript) so that's why I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function into another function to achieve this. I've done it for `dropClaw`, and it should be clear from my example how to do also extract `startClaw`.

```
function operateClaw(func){
    var readCount = 0;
    for(var isRead in qdata){
        readCount++;
        if(qdata[isRead]['reading'] == true){
            return;
        }else if(readCount == 5){
            func();
        }
    }
}

function drop () {
    if(isDropping){ return; } //prevent multiple clicks
    stopSwingClaw();
    isDropping = true;  
    MCI = setInterval(moveDown,20); //start heartbeat
}

function dropClaw () {
    operateClaw(drop);
}
```